# How can I install KateSql plugin?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plugins, kate

I am slightly new to Ubuntu and I just installed kate by typing `sudo apt-get install kate`. Now I want to install this [kate sql plugin](http://kate-editor.org/2010/07/29/katesql-a-new-plugin-for-kate/) and google is not helping me. I downloaded a punch of files from [here](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php/Kate+SQL+Plugin?content=126861)

- what should I do with these files ?
- Where should I put them ?
- Would you please tell me how can I install this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the comments on [the first link](http://kate-editor.org/2010/07/29/katesql-a-new-plugin-for-kate/) you gave, it looks like you'll need to build it yourself, unless you're running KDE4.6:

> [image: avatar for Mentasti]
>   *Marco Mentasti* since this plugin was released after KDE 4.5
>   feature freeze, it will be included in
>   KDE 4.6

---

> [image: avatar for Volker]*Volker Lanz*
>    This is really awsome stuff.
>   Thanks for creating this! Looking
>   forward to getting my hands on it.
>
> [image: avatar for Cullmann]*Christoph
>   Cullmann* You can get it today:
>   http://kate-editor.org/get-it/

The link, [kate-editor.org/get-it](http://kate-editor.org/get-it/), goes to a page with detailed build instructions.  This should include code that contains the SQL plugin.

Answer (score 1):

**Resent Kate/KDE/Kubuntu**

And after the KDE 4.6 - at here the KDE 4.7.4: ( Press F1, The Kate Handbook or online: http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/applications/kate/index.html )

> Open Kate's configuration dialog with Settings → Configure Kate...
>   Select Application → Plugins to choose the wanted plugins.

[image]

**Links:**

- KDE: http://www.kde.org/
- Ubuntu Derivatives: http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu/derivatives
- Kubuntu: http://www.kubuntu.org/